# Nhibernate/hibernate Avoid Insert in joined table or view

Tags: nhibernate, join, subclass

I have to join a entity with a view to retrieve some data into properties

```
<join table="XXVIEW" optional="true">
      <key column="ID_ENT" />
      <property name="Prop1" insert ="false" update ="false" />
      <property name="Prop2" insert ="false" update ="false" />
      <property name="Prop3" insert ="false" update ="false" />          
</join>
```

But when i try to save (insert) it fails becouse it try to insert a record in XXVIEW with ID_Ent

I need to have some properties in this entity get from various calculations or joins and to have as single properties non in a object property like a component.

Can i skip this insert ??? or can i map this properties in other way?

This properties is in a joined subclass.
TIA
Adb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of marking it as optional you can try mark it as inverse http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join

> **inverse** (optional - defaults to
>   false): If enabled, Hibernate will not
>   try to insert or update the properties
>   defined by this join.

```
<join table="XXVIEW" inverse="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a record on a view, on your class try adding the `mutable='false'`

```
<class name="ActorView" mutable="false">
...
```

If you are trying to save back then I suspect you will need to forget about the view and turn it into a fully blown entity with collections defined.

Comment: I need to save the entity and the others properties but not the ones get from view that is  read only